# Twilio Issue com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.UserAgent in Android

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

Please check below logs what was the issue.

```
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to access field com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.config.UserAgentConfig$Callbacks com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.config.UserAgentConfig.callbacks from an object argument of type com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.UserAgent: 0xaf709180
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to GetObjectField
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.twilio.client.impl.session.Transport.close(boolean)
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "Thread-43753" prio=5 tid=10 Runnable
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x2ae62e20 self=0xb8e7b540
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=20743 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9f2e9930
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 1464818284 902873682 4519 ) utm=96 stm=50 core=4 HZ=100
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0x9f1ed000-0x9f1ef000 stackSize=1014KB
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-01 15:14:12.763 20707-20743/com.reach.communications A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035c6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+116)
```

How can i handle this issue.

Comment: The error is difficult to decipher without understanding what your code is trying to do. Can you post a snippet along with the logs?

Comment: i solve it this issue using  compile 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.14'

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it sorted. Can you want to post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this issue using

> compile 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.14'